# Update excel file in SharePoint programmatically

Tags: c#, asp.net, sharepoint

I am just wondering if it is possible to have a Web Part in Share Point 2010 Foundation that will allow the user to enter in some details, just strings, then when they click save it will search through an excel file get an ID number and give it back to the user. It will the populate the row with the new ID number with the details that the user has provided?

If can help me know if this is possible or not I would greatly appreciate it.

Thanks,
Stuart.

Comment: There are a zillion option listed in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/151005/create-excel-xls-and-xlsx-file-from-c

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [Aspose.Cells](http://www.aspose.com/categories/.net-components/aspose.cells-for-.net/default.aspx). You can use it to manipulate excel files in any way you like.

Answer (score 0):

If the Excel file is in a document library, [SoftArtisans OfficeWriter](http://www.officewriter.com/), another 3rd party library for manipulating Excel files, comes with [SharePoint integration](http://wiki.softartisans.com/display/EW8/SharePointIntegration).

(Disclaimer, I work for SoftArtisans)